# Proving that $N$ is a manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm dealing with the following exercise from Munkres' "Analysis on Manifolds":

> Let $f:\mathbb R^{n+k}\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be of class $C^r$. Let $M$ be the set of all $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. Assume that $M$ is non-empty and that $Df(x)$ has rank $n$ for $x \in M$. Then $M$ is a $k$-manifold without boundary in $\mathbb R^{n+k}$. Furthermore, if $N$ is the set of all $x$ for which
>
> $$f_1(x)=\dots=f_{n-1}(x)=0 \, \, \text{ and } \, \, f_n(x)\geq 0$$
>
> and if the matrix $$\partial (f_1, \dots, f_{n-1})/\partial x$$has rank $n-1$ at each point of $N$, then $N$ is a $k+1$ manifold and $\partial N=M$.

The first part (that states that $M$ is a $k$-manifold without boundary) is clear for me. However, I don't know what to do to prove the second part.

Comment: Do you mean (about $N$) $(k+1)$-manifold? $N$ has $n-1$ equations, so its dimension is (away from the boundary) $k+1$ (for the same reason that $M$ has dimension $k$).

Comment: woops, sorry :p just edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For points in $N$ with $f_n(x)>0$ there is the assumption on the rank of $\partial(f_1,\dots,f_{n-1})/\partial x$. Hence you get local charts (in dimension $k+1$) by the same argument you use for $M$ in dimension $k$.

Hence the only problem is to get appropriate charts for $N$ around points $x\in M$ (in which the assumption on the rank is automatically satisfied).  For such a point $x$, the standard proof that $M$ is a submanifold gives you an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb R^{n+k}$ and smooth functions $g_1,\dots, g_k:U\to\mathbb R$ such that $(f_1,\dots,f_n,g_1,\dots,g_k)$ defines a diffeomorphism from $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb R^{n+k}$. Then you use $(g_1,\dots,g_k)$ as a chart on $U\cap M$. But in the same way, you can use $(f_n,g_1,\dots, g_k)$ as a chart for $U\cap N$, which by assumption now has values in a half-space, thus showing that $N$ is a submanifold of dimension $k+1$ with boundary $M$.

Comment: Hello Andreas. What is the standard proof that $M$ is a submanifold? The prove I know is to show that $M$ is locally the graph of a function.

Comment: There are several equivalent condtions (local parametrization, locally graph of a function, local regular zero set) and the condition, which looks like the general definition of a submanifold: Up to a diffeomorphism, $M$ locally looks like $\mathbb R^k\subset\mathbb R^{n+k}$. The explicit form is more or less spelled out in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about this is to first consider just the first $(n-1)$ maps, into $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. There the preimage of $0$ is a $(k+1)$-manifold, let's call it $D$ [this is by the first part]. Then consider, by restriction, the map $f_n:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The preimage of $(0,\infty)$ is an open subset of $D$ (by continuity), so is a $(k+1)$ dimensional manifold. The preimage of $0$ is $M$ (by the first part). Showing everything meshes well ($M$ is the boundary, etc.) Can be done by using the fact that, locally, $f_n$ looks like $f_n(x _1,\ldots,x_{k+1})=x_{k+1}$.

Comment: How do we know that the rank of $d(f_1, \dots, f_n)(x)$ for every $x$ such that $f_1(x)=\dots=f_{n-1}(x)$ is $n-1$? We only know that this is true when $f_n(x)\geq 0$.

Comment: @ViniciusRodrigues: I should have written this more cleanly, but $N$ is an open set of the space where the rank is maximum: you are right that what I call $D$ may not be a manifold, but an open subset of it is a manifold, and $N$ lives entirely in there.